# Delete duplicate records for specific criteria | MS Access

Tags: mysql, ms-access

Essentially I have the following called `Table1` with columns `OrderNum` and `Book` there should never be duplicate records of any kind of `Book` for each `OrderNum`, if there is it needs to identified and deleted.

[image]

**For example:**

`OrderNum` 1 should only have `Book1` listed once so the query must identify the other 2 `Book1` listed for `OrderNum` 1 and delete them.

`OrderNum` 4 should only have `Book2` listed once so the query must identify the other `Book2` listed for `OrderNum` 4 and delete it.

**After the query runs Table1 Should look like this:**

[image]

I am working with MS Access queries but I am looking for a solution that could work for an mySQL query as well.

Comment: What happened to order # 2?  There seems to be data gone missing here.

Comment: How so? Order #2 has no duplicate Books listed, so there are no records to delete. The same goes for Order #3.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this gracefully on either MySQL or Access, because your table doesn't have a primary key column, which it rightfully should have.  On Access, you could try creating a new table, then populating it using the following query:

```
INSERT INTO yourNewTable (OrderNum, Book)
SELECT DISTINCT OrderNum, Book
FROM yourTable;
```

Then, delete `yourTable` after you are done with the above query.

If you had a primary key/auto increment column in your table, let's say `id`, then you could use the following delete statement directly:

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
              WHERE t2.OrderNum = t1.OrderNum AND
                    t2.Book = b1.Book AND
                    t2.id < t1.id);
```

This would leave, for each `(OrderNum, Book)` combination, the single record among duplicates which happens to have the *lowest* `id` value.